# Margin effecting center aligned items in flexbox row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I'm pretty new when it comes to flexbox but it seems a lot of properties work the same way.

However, when it comes to align items center I'm used to the way inline-block handles margins where it creates a space within the whole row even if it's on a specific element.

With flexbox it seems to only move that element off the axis.  Fiddle attached, let me know if I am doing something wrong here.  Using bootstrap css with only a few other styles to show what's going on.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/fv1gm67f/3/

```
<div id="header-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row flex-wrap align-items-center">
        <div class="header-top-social-media-icons-outer col col-auto">
          <nav class="header-top-social-media-icons text-center icons-circle icons-sm">
            <ul class="social-media-icons">
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="header-top-menu-outer col col-auto">
          <nav class="header-top-menu">
            <ul id="menu-header-top-menu" class="menu">
              <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sample Page</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Blog Posts</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont think you question is clear on what you want. What is the issue your having. I mean in the fiddle what is not the way its supposed to be? If you are talking about verticle alignment of the icons not matching with the nav bar links then you just need to remove the bottom margin set in `.social-media-icons li` class.

Comment: I've added an image to represent what I meant.  You are correct in assuming that's what I need to be aligned center. However, I wanted to know if there was a way to make it behave like inline-block elements where it would create space for both elements even if only one has margin.

Comment: Oh i see. Please check my answer below for your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood you correctly. You want to keep the 2 columns aligned vertically automatically. I think you can achieve this with the property `align-self:baseline`. Please add the following css class to your fiddle and you will see that whether you give margin bottom or top to the icons col, the right column will align itself based on that margin and keep in line.

```
.col-auto{
    align-self:baseline;
 }
```

Hope this answers your question.

**[EDIT For More Explaination]**

As per your comment you are correct that align-self is for items within flexbox. If you notice then your `.flex-wrap` class is putting `display:flex` on main container with has 2 columns child as flex items. And then you have display:flex on the inner nav ul as well which is nested. You needed to set the align-self to baseline for the parent flexbox in order for the 2 col items to align to each other.

Here is a very good article with complete guide to flexbox.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Hope this explanation gives more info to others as well. 
Happy Coding :)

Comment: I see your solution works, but I was under the impression that `align-self`property was only good for elements within a flexbox.  Is this not true?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/fv1gm67f/6/ here is a visual fiddle of what Nasir T solved.

Comment: NM, I see that the `.flex-wrap` class does put `display: flex` on the parent.

Comment: This is an excellent solution and what I was looking for, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Give your social media icons a margin of 0.

```css
 .social-media-icons li {
   margin-bottom:0px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Russell Alan alluded to, it is a box model issue.  The `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` on the `ul.social-media-icons` element is throwing the y axis off.  The `li` elements also have a `margin-bottom` that adds to the issue.  The following CSS should fix the issue:

> **CSS**

```
/*This is so you can get a visual on exactly what the boxes are doing*/
.col-auto {
    background-color: #CCC;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}

ul.social-media-icons {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.social-media-icons li {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/fv1gm67f/5/)

Ultimately, however, I think it might be best to set a `min-height` on the `.row.flex-wrap` children.

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-block; margin-bottom: Npx` does not affect the centering of other `display: inline-block` elements within a common parent element.

https://jsfiddle.net/dkoadaya/

I modified your fiddle above to center some inline-block elements and show that the behavior is the same.